# Bibliography Bibtex with book pages

Tags: nodes

Is there any way of having a **shared** bibtex bibliography in a book ?

For example, I want to have one book page "References" where I put all my references and then in all my book pages, I can reference each entry of the bibliography.

Comment: do you want it to be part of the book. if not the following module is some thing to look at http://drupal.org/project/lexicon

Comment: Actually, it is more a bibliography that I want. I just found this module http://drupal.org/project/biblio. I am also looking for some integration with organic groups.